# How to show authentication & authorization within metadata operation page

Tags: servicestack

I noticed the operation metadata page shows the "Rest user defined endpoint" even if not explicitly added as DTO attribute, but defined within the AppHost.Configure method.

I wonder if it would be possible to show within the metadata page, among other operation details, if a given operation(DTO) requires authentication (defined at operation or service level) and all the required authorizations(roles and permissions) if any.

Comment: Please [add this as a feature request](http://servicestack.uservoice.com/forums/176786-feature-requests) so we don't forget!

Comment: Ok thanks. Did it: http://servicestack.uservoice.com/forums/176786-feature-requests/suggestions/7601595-show-required-authentication-authorization-withi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has now been added on the Metadata index page which will display a yellow key for Services which require authentication, e.g:

[image: Authentication in Metadata Index]

When you mouse over the key it will also show which permissions or roles the Service needs.

It's also added on the metadata detail page which will list which permissions/roles are required (if any), e.g:

[image: Authentication in Metadata Detail]

This feature is available from v4.0.43+ which is now [available on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet).